# Styled components for colored tags

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Styled components looks great, but I am having trouble organizing my components. My first venture with is a tag list, that automatically colors the tags. After some trial I came up with a component that can be used like this:

```
// An array of tags. The string hashes determine the color
<ColorTags tags={post.frontmatter.tags} inline/>
```

It is implemented as follows:

```
components/
    ColorTags      // functional component
    ColorTagLI    // styled component
    ColorTagUL   // styled component
```

With:

```
// ColorTags
import ColorTagLI from './ColorTagLI'
import ColorTagUL from './ColorTagUL'

export default ({tags, inline}) => 
    <ColorTagUL>
        {tags.map( tag =>
            <ColorTagLI key={tag} colorString={tag} inline>
                <Link to="/">
                    {tag}
                </Link>
            </ColorTagLI>
        )}
    </ColorTagUL>



// ColorTagUL
export default styled.ul`
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
`


// ColorTagLI
const colorHash = new ColorHash({lightness: [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]});

const hslColor = cString => {
    const [h, s, l] = colorHash.hsl(cString)
    return `hsl(${h}, ${s*100}%, ${l*100}%)`
}

export default styled.li`
    color: white;
    background-color: ${props => hslColor(props.colorString)};
    display: ${props => props.inline ? 'inline-block' : 'block'};
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    margin: 0.25rem;
    > a { text-decoration: none; color: white; }
`
```

Some questions I have:

- What's a good way to discern between styled and regular components? I
  decided on appending the HTML tag to the styled components, since
  they are always tied to that.
- Is it not a problem to have the `Link` tag inside a Styled component?
- Should the ColorTag components be in a folder of themselves? Because they are tightly coupled.
- Is using the`inline` prop a smart way to switch between configurations? It may
  result in a lot of conditional statements for margins, padding and
  media queries... Perhaps better make two different components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [utility function isStyledComponent.](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#isstyledcomponent)
2. Why would it be a problem to have a `Link` component inside styled component?
3. Matter of opinion, if you believe they are tightly coupled you can create `/ColorTag` directory with `index.js` file that exports only what should be exposed.
4. Yes it may result in a lot of conditional statements, that's why you can [extend styles on styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles).

I hope I understood you right and my answers are clear.

Comment: Some great pointers, and all is clear! Regaring the Link component: I thought that best practise was to have the Styled components at the lowest level of hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry to abuse you for a follow-up question, but... anything made with Styled Components (or any ccs-in-js solution) seems really dependent on it, including the functional parts. That would make the components really hard to exchange (unless the next person uses the same library). How do you see this? Isn't it bad practise to make components that can only be used by a fraction of the React ecosystem?

Comment: That's a good question and [there is a section in documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#i-am-a-library-author-should-i-bundle-styledcomponents-with-my-library) that answers that partially. With every library I worked with `css` is exposed in a separate file or as a CDN this gives users ability to work with tools they want and use global styles for installed modules. However, if your company agrees that all of the projects will use `styled-components` then it is reasonable to create a library that depends on them.